# Oracle to_date format issue

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an insert statement, where one of the inserted fields is date. I use `to_date` function to convert string to date in this way:

```
to_date('10-MAY-10', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

It works fine, but I found, that it allows also variants like:

```
to_date('10?MAY?10', 'DD-MON-RR')
to_date('10+MAY+10', 'DD-MON-RR')
```

I'm expecting an Oracle error, however it makes an insert. Could you please explain why or give a reference to relevant documentation?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924

Comment: You shouldn't use `TO_DATE` with month names without specifying the language (e.g. `to_date('10-MAY-10', 'DD-MON-RR', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN'`). Otherwise you depend on session settings that can be set to a different language where 'MAY' has no meaning. Is there a reason why you don't use a simple date literal (e.g. `date'2010-05-10'`)?

Comment: In my application I use date in the way you said '2015-05-10'. I just want to know why Oracle doesn't reject values like '2015?05?10' and is it possible to restrict delimiters to '-' only.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle will test for other formats if it fails to find a match in the string - you can see the rules for what it looks for [here in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#sthref461).

As an aside, years have four digits. Please make sure you specify all four when you provide a date-as-a-string, where possible; it saves the database from having to guess and potentially getting it wrong. I.e. your original example should be:

`to_date('10-05-2010', 'DD-MM-YYYY')`

If you need to restrict the date-as-a-string to a specific format, you can use the fx format modifier, which is mentioned earlier in the same document I linked to previously.

eg. `to_date('10/05/2010', 'dd-mm-yyyy')` would match but `to_date('10/05/2010', 'fxdd-mm-yyyy')` would fail